# Google analytics and curl

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics

I am scrapping data from a website using CURL. These are 40k pages which i need to scrap using CURL.

Here, i want to know that Google Analytics will show this traffic or not in website owner Analytics account ?

Comment: Tracking code is JavaScript,  I don't think your Curl script is going to run the JavaScript.  (so probably not)

Comment: So owner of the website can not track this bot attack correct ?

Comment: The owner cannot track this using Google Analytics. Since this amounts basically to a DOS attack he will probably notice (at the latest when his site goes down, but there are tools to spot unusual traffic, especially when it comes from a single IP). It is polite to ask permission before doing something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics works by creating a XHR request in **javascript**. That's why you traditionally see the classic script tag at the end or beginning of an HTML file.

```
<script>
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () { (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments) }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-5620270-1');        
    ga('set', 'dimension1', '1452546');         
    ga('set', 'dimension2', '|php|curl|google-analytics|');         
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    var _qevents = _qevents || [],
        _comscore = _comscore || [];
    _qevents.push({ qacct: "p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc" });
</script>
```

By curling a site, you will not alert the webmaster from this particular piece of code as nothing will run the javascript...

**However**

It's totally possible that this will show on google analytics provided that the webmaster is implementing [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/p/serversidegoogleanalytics/) server side. It's unlikely this is being done. I've never personally heard of it. If you are worrying about being stealthy (I won't press why) then be conscious that Google Analytics is not the only form of tracking. I frequently refer to my nginx logs if I get an unusual amount of traffic to checkout what bots are hitting my site. Services like Loggly and New Relic are popular and occasional custom solutions are implemented (depending on the size of the company). There's a good chance your ip will be blacklisted if you crawl this site aggressively.

***Note:*** Not a great question for Stackoverflow. Why not checkout some of the other Stack Exchange sites like maybe [webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)?